# Creating a view-field with the sender's domain

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

*It's cleanup time.*

I'd like to cleanaup my mails. Therefore it would be nice to have all emails sorted/grouped by domains (optionally by TLD's as well).

I'm already using something similar - the field for the sender's email adress, which was described at `https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/viewsenderaddress.htm`, which works perfectly. So I think something similar can be done for the domain (and TLD) as well.

Has someone here either a working solution ans share it or guide me how to achieve this.

Thx.

*Remarks:*
It's Outlook 2007 without Exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks to a big search engine when using the proper words solution can be found. :-)*

I have found a solution which displays the Senders Domain: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2190-outlook-view-sender-domain.html

and to Sort and Group on the Domain use
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2187-outlook-sort-group-by-sender-domain.html